# Viewing PICamera V2 via VNC

Tags: raspicam, vnc

I'm using RPI3, Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and PiCamera V2.
All is working well.

While using VNC - I don't get any stream view ( raspivid, raspistill and Python ).

Is there a way to config PiCamera or VNC to be able to do so ?
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to turn on the [direct capture mode](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-minecraft) in the VNC server on the RPi.

To turn this feature on, open the VNC Server dialog (on the RPi), navigate to Menu > Options > Troubleshooting, and select Enable experimental direct capture mode.

The link above gives more details.

Comment: Thank you. Currently RPI is under Ubuntu MATE 16.0.4 - and x11VNC is installed. Can it be done under ubuntu ?

Comment: @Guy D, according to the RealVNC website, they are the only ones who support a direct capture mode for the RPi. You should be able to install RealVNC in your Ubuntu environment. You should be able to find installation in at the link in my answer.